# как правильно сделать многопоточность что бы программа не зависала?

Tags: c#

Всем привет!
Как сделать правильно многопоточность, что бы программа не зависала? Я делал список `List<Thread> threads = new List<threads>();`  туда помещал потоки, а потом по кнопке их всех останавливал проходясь циклом по ним `threads[i].Abort()`. Функция потоков выглядела так:

```
void foo(object obj) {
   while(true) {
       FooStruct fs = (FooStruct)obj;
       AddLog(fs.arg1);
       AddLog(fs.arg2);
       AddLog(fs.arg3;
  }
}
```

Эта функция выводит текст в richtextbox. Но когда юзер запускает очень много таких потоков (штук по 1к), то программа зависает намертво. Как сделать что бы сколько не запускай - программа их отрабатывала? Спасибо всем! Если что, это мне нужно для парсера сайтов, в аргументы передаются url сайтов, но я привёл пример немного легче.

Comment: _выводит текст в richtextbox_ - тормозит именно работа с GUI-контролами. Чтобы не тормозило, нужно обращаться к ним как можно реже, скажем, не чаще раза в секунду.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не совсем так, в моём парсере в функции потока нет вообще обращения к UI контроллам. Мне кажется тут проблема в том, что я криво создаю потоки. Есть другое решение что бы создать много потоков и что бы они работали сразу все?

Comment: В данной формулировке на ваш вопрос невозможно ответить. Покажите больше кода.

Comment: Лучше использовать async/await - они создают треды сами и вам не нужно заморачиваться над ними, это высокоуровневая абстракция над многопоточным программированием. В случае работы с GUI ничего подсказать не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Делать остановку потоков в другом потоке.
У вас синхронный поток (главный) останавливает в цикле потоки отсюда и зависание.

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую!

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/484528)

Comment: @DaemonHK, коментарии для уточнения вопроса. А я отписал ответ, так как понял в чем вопрос.

Comment: @AzizUmarov сделал, но всё равно зависает =(

Comment: @Armadillo-CLD идея простая вызвал и забыл. Периодически проверяешь статус потоков. Скорее всего у вас потоки блокируются иначе откуда зависание

Comment: @AzizUmarov Оу! На гитхабе только что нашел сорцы какого то парсера, уряяя. Всем спасибо!

Comment: @AzizUmarov извиняюсь, видимо на автомате сработал

Comment: @DaemonHK всё норм, бывает.